# CFMail with attachment is being sent and is in undelivr folder

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I'm using cfmail to send attachments with a remove option.
And I know it's working because I am using Gmail as my mail server and I can see the email in my sent items folder in Gmail.

There are files in the C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\Mail\Undelivr folder.
When I move them to the C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\Mail\spool folder, they get moved back into Undelivr again.

`mail.log` says things like:

> "Error","scheduler-0","06/09/15","11:16:55",,"javax.mail.MessagingException:
>   IOException while sending message;   nested exception is:
>     java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myDomainName\myFileName.pdf (The system cannot find
>   the file specified)"

So when I go to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myDomainName\, sure enough, the attachment is not there. But I can see that the customer got the email with the attachment because I can see it in my sent items folder in Gmail.

So the email got sent, but it's in the Undelivr folder.

Comment: Are you sending same attachments to multiple email ids using some sort of looping. Because if that is the case, the attachments will be removed after they have been sent to first email id and thus the attachments will be unavailable for the second time. And thus the error message you are getting is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Lets see your CFMAIL and CFMAILPARAM tags.  Any chance you have the attribute remove="true" set?

Comment: Plus 1 to get his reputation high enough to post comments.